# Amazon Affiliate Banner only visible for logged in users like Admin

Tags: wordpress, banner, amazon-product-api, affiliate

I am trying to display Amazon Banner on my blog post. But the Banner is only visible to the logged in users likes Admin. When I am trying to check the same from other PC or browser it's not visible at all.
I have tried to check using the inspect element console but there is no error for this. As well as in the frontend source code the Amazon Banner is not present.

Has anyone faced this issue before? Initially, I also thought it might be due to the plugin issue from Cache or Security Plugin like [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/amazon-ad-banners-are-not-visible-in-wordpress-site/). So, I have tried disabling and also replacing them with different ones. But the problem still persists.

**Sample Page**: https://swarnathesagigirl.com/beauty/maybelline-best-drugstore-lipstick/

- Website Platform: WordPress
- Cache Plugin: WP Rocket
- Security: Wordfence Free Version
- Blog Editor: Elementor Pro
- SEO: Previously Yoast, switched to RankMath

**View from Admin/Editor Screen**

[image]

**View from Frontend as logged in User Screen**

[image]

**View from Visitor Screen**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying with Amazon Ads, I went for other ad publishers like media.net and propeller. I had the same problem with everyone. Then I understood it must be something to do with Server. So I contacted my Server Support (Hostgator). After checking the server logs they told me there were some **ModSecurity rules getting triggered** due to which the ads were getting removed from serverside before reaching web browser. After the support fix, I enabled my wp plugins but again the ad went AWOL. So as I had earlier mentioned there was a similar issue due to Cache plugin. I went ahead and disabled the Cache plugin and checked. The culprit was WP Rocket this time. After digging a while it turns out to be the issue with **WP Rocket JS Minification**

[Snapshot of WP Rocket JS Minification Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNM9a.png)

After unchecking all the problem was finally fixed. I hope this will help others as well. This issue had bugged me for over a month now.